# Point project onto plane

Tags: math, graphics

Given a p point(3D) and a plane(contain a base point and a normal vector), how should I project point onto plane?

Details:
Point p is a 3D vector(x1,y1,z1), and plane is represent by a point q at the plane and a 3D normal vector l(x3,y3,z3). All data is defined and no camera projection. The task is to project p onto the plane, return its new position(x1',y1',z1').

Comment: This is too broad, we need more information, what are you trying to do? Is this for 3D graphics? Geometry? Is this for the Camera projection process? Is this for finding the shortest distance of a point to a plane?

Comment: Sorry. point p is a 3D vector(x1,y1,z1), and plane is represent by a point q at the plane and a 3D normal vector l(x3,y3,z3). All data is defined and no camera projection. The task is to project p onto the plane, return its new position(x1',y1',z1').

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653628/getting-closest-point-on-a-plane, or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113780/fast-algorithm-to-find-the-x-closest-points-to-a-given-point-on-a-plane, or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55189333/how-to-get-distance-from-point-to-plane-in-3d ... Really. This question may be one of THE most documented 3D graphics tasks ever.